# ¿Cómo pasar dos parámetros con PathInfo en c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, rutas

Tengo un controlador en C#, que a su vez tiene un método el cual recibe dos parámetros, desde JS hago un location.href para llamar al controlador (controlador/accion/parametros), pero tengo la duda sobre la sintaxis para la ruta cuando son dos parámetros los que hay que enviar. ¿Se separan con coma, barra o cómo? Además, es necesario modificar el archivo RouteConfig.cs? En donde esta la definición de las rutas:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: En ese caso, la URL debe estar formada por los parámetros que desees: `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{otroParametro}",`. y en tu Controller deberá recibir ese parámetro: `public IHttpActionResult NombreAction(int Id, string otroParametro) { ... }`

Comment: Ya le coloqué a la url el segundo parámetro y lo coloqué opcional para que no de error en caso de no recibirlo, pero como debe ser la dirección a enviar?, es decir, cuál es la sintaxis para pasar los dos parámetros? Así? "controlador/accion/parametro1/parametro2" o "controlador/accion/parametro1,parametro2" porque de cualquiera de las dos maneras me devuelve este error: HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request

Comment: La direción debe ser tal cual aparece en la configuración:`controlador/accion/parametro1/parametro2`, si te fijas aparece con diagonales en el archivo de configuraión

Comment: Al dividir los parametros con una diagonal me da error, aunque lo configure asi en el RouteConfig.

Comment: ¿qué error te da?